# Large Labels With Small Input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a web application with a number of lengthy forms (~30 fields each). Many of the fields have long label names and I'd prefer to have short input fields. I'm arranging these fields into rows of 3-5 fields each.

An example where I'd like the label to overflow into the additional white space between form fields rather than wrap the text:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Oopmaxind, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Oopmaxind, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Oopmaxind, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Alternately, if anyone has an example of elegantly designed forms that have long labels and many fields, please share.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered abbreviating your label names? e.g. max instead of maximum or Ind. rather than Individual? Also, how many labels are affected - not all 30?

Comment: I’d say about 1/3 of the labels are effective. And unfortunately they can’t be abbreviated. I’ve considered implementing tooltips instead of labels, but I’d much rather stick with labels if possible.